# How to return value of function with Ajax inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response, openlayers

I know this issue have been discussed well [on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but I can't seem to find how to apply this to my function. I keep getting undefined variables logs.

```
function requestLayersFromGeoserver() {

    var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities", 
        success: function(response) {
            result = parser.read(response);
            var layersArray = result.Capability.Layer.Layer;
            layersNameArray = [];

            for(i=0;i<layersArray.length;i++){
                layersNameArray.push(layersArray[i].Name)
            }
        }
    }); 

    return layersNameArray
}
```

How can I fix that so that I get the layersNameArray variable when I call the function ?

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get any better answer than the one you linked. If you tried the solutions and they didn't work, then post your actual attempts in a question.

Comment: This is the real message "Embrace the asynchronous nature of JavaScript!".  Javascript is full of code that takes time to execute.  So instead of wanting your function to return a value, you send a request, and you define a function that handles what ever you wanted to do with that value.  That function will be called when ever the service is ready (for example when Ajax returns a value).